# Install vmplayer on cloud

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, cloud

Can you please let me know on this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234475/vmplayer-on-centos6

It was closed there as off topic. Hope this is the right place for this question.

Comment: It's not on topic here, either, and linking back to the SO question is not a good way to ask.  If you post the question on SU and provide more details, it *might* be ok there.

Answer (score 1):

To see if you even have the `vmmon` module, run `lsmod |grep vmmon`

To load it, run `modprobe vmmon`

Comment: It seems like its not a topic on here too according to the comment above. Have post it on SU as said above http://superuser.com/questions/415547/install-vmplayer-on-cloud-centos

Comment: If you can post your comment there will let you know the result. Do not want to violate any rules here. Thank you for the response and help.